# External HTML page and wordpress in same root folder

Tags: html, wordpress, root

I got a quick question:

I have a HTML page and my wordpress blog in the root folder due to some technical integration's used in it. What I have done to achieve this:

I simply saved my HTML page as "index.html" and put in the root folder that holds the Wordpress "index.php" file. The "index.html" automatically was granted a higher status and opened as my home page.

My question:

How this affects my SEO? 
How my sitemap is affected by that?
Since I use SEO plugin by Yoast, this plugin builds my sitemap but I am not sure that it will include my homepage.

I am opened to your interactions and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with .htaccess file. hope it will help you to open first index.php

Comment: why do you need an index.html page? can't you integrate it in index.php of wordpress? I'm sure there is a better solution for this, what are you using the page for? when do you decide when you want the index.html page and when the index.php page? or do you bypass index.php with your index.html?